# To-do app with TypeScript backend (violations of TS best practices or unidiomatic code)

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, express.js, to-do-list

The [working code in full is here](https://github.com/JohnnyMarnell/tasks-ts).

It's a **To-Do App with a TypeScript backend**, written as practice for an upcoming 4-hour interview for a TypeScript backend role. My colleague and I would like to know, **does this implementation violate any commonly held TS best practices or employ unidiomatic patterns?** Neither of us have TS backgrounds though we do in other backend (Java, C++, etc.) Stylistic critique welcome too.

I'm given to understand that the following 3 files hold the main sources of interest:

#### index.ts

```
import express, { ErrorRequestHandler } from "express"
import * as tasks from "./controllers/tasks.controller"
import crypto from "crypto"
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler"
import { DatabaseError } from "pg"

// Configure middleware for parsing JSON and URL-encoded data
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// Define routes
app.get("/tasks", asyncHandler(tasks.getTasks))
app.get("/tasks/:id", asyncHandler(tasks.getTaskById))
app.post("/tasks", asyncHandler(tasks.createTask))
app.put("/tasks/:id", asyncHandler(tasks.updateTask))
app.delete("/tasks/:id", asyncHandler(tasks.deleteTask))

app.get("/ping", async (req, res) => res.json({ pong: true }))

// Log bubbled up errors, with generated error ID
const errorLogger: ErrorRequestHandler = async (err, req, res, next) => {
  // If db column doesn't exist, or bad value, assume 400 Bad Request
  if (err instanceof DatabaseError) {
    const cause: any = err.cause
    console.warn("Database error", req.url, cause?.stack || err.stack)

    if (["42703", "22P02"].includes(err.code || "")) {
      res.status(400).send()
      return
    }
  }

  const errorId = crypto
    .createHash("md5")
    .update(crypto.randomBytes(20))
    .digest("hex")
  console.error("Server error", errorId, req.url, err.stack)

  res.status(500).json({ errorId: errorId })
}
app.use(errorLogger)

// Start server
const PORT = 3000
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`)
})

export default app
```

#### tasks.controllers.ts

```
import { Handler } from "express"
import * as store from "../store/tasks.store"

export const getTasks: Handler = async (req, res) => {
  const tasks = await store.findAllTasks()
  return res.status(200).json({ tasks: tasks })
}

export const getTaskById: Handler = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  const tasks = await store.findTasksById([id])
  return tasks.length ? res.json(tasks[0]) : res.status(404).send()
}

export const createTask: Handler = async (req, res) => {
  const task: store.Task = req.body
  if (!task.title || !task.description) {
    return res.status(400).send()
  }

  const id = await store.createTask(task)
  return res.status(201).json({ task_id: id })
}

export const updateTask: Handler = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  const deleted = await store.updateTask(id, req.body as store.Task)
  return res.status(deleted ? 200 : 404).send()
}

export const deleteTask: Handler = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  const numDeleted = await store.deleteTasksById([id])
  return res.status(numDeleted ? 204 : 404).send()
}
```

#### tasks.store.ts

```
import db from "../store/database"

export const findAllTasks = async (): Promise<Task[]> => {
  const qr = await db.query("SELECT * FROM tasks")
  return qr.rows.map(mapTask)
}

export const findTasksById = async (ids: string[]): Promise<Task[]> => {
  const sql = `SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_id IN (${idx(ids)})`
  const qr = await db.query(sql, ids)
  return qr.rows.map(mapTask)
}

export const deleteTasksById = async (ids: string[]): Promise<number> => {
  const sql = `DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task_id IN (${idx(ids)})`
  const qr = await db.query(sql, ids)
  return qr.rowCount ?? 0
}

export const createTask = async (task: Task): Promise<string> => {
  const t = new TaskEntity(task)
  const qr = await db.query(
    "INSERT INTO tasks (title, description, completed) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING task_id",
    [t.title, t.description, t.completed],
  )
  return qr.rows[0].task_id
}

export const updateTask = async (id: string, task: Task): Promise<boolean> => {
  const [keys, vals] = [Object.keys(task).join(","), Object.values(task)]
  const qr = await db.query(
    `UPDATE tasks SET (${keys}) = ROW(${idx(vals)}) WHERE task_id = $${vals.length + 1}`,
    vals.concat([id]),
  )
  return qr.rowCount === 1
}

export interface Task {
  task_id: string | null
  title: string | null
  description: string | null
  completed: boolean
}

export class TaskEntity implements Task {
  readonly task_id: string | null
  readonly title: string | null
  readonly description: string | null
  readonly completed: boolean

  constructor(opts: TaskEntity) {
    this.task_id = opts.task_id
    this.title = opts.title
    this.description = opts.description
    this.completed = opts.completed ?? false
  }
}

const idx = (arr: any[]) => arr.map((v, i) => `$${i + 1}`).join(",")
const mapTask = (row: Task) => new TaskEntity(row)
```

#### Some areas of concern

1. Querying the database without a (heavyweight) ORM or defining an interface or POJO object.
2. File naming and organization.
3. Style of using imports.
4. Exporting too many default functions instead of one `TaskManager` or otherwise named class.
5. My colleague's particular use of Jest and Express routes. (He comments that NestJS (not NextJS) looks similar to the Java/Spring world we're both more familiar with, but it's too much to learn in the time he has left.)
6. The error-handler setup.